# undefined method `deciaml' when migrating

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Hello I have a migration which creates a table (and adds a column to an existing table).

```
class CreateAdminModule < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admin_module do |t|
      t.decimal :no_of_devices_multiplier
      t.decimal :option_1_multiplier
      t.decimal :option_2_multiplier
      t.deciaml :option_3_multiplier
      t.decimal :option_4_multiplier
      t.decimal :option_5_multiplier

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  add_column :admin_user_roles, :module_admin, :boolean
end
```

I am using the mysql2 gem. When I run the migration, I get this:

```
c:\Sites\site>rake db:migrate
-- add_column(:admin_user_roles, :module_admin, :boolean)
   -> 0.4726s
==  CreateAdminCirrus: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:admin_module)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method 'deciaml' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x3c00a80>c:/Sites/site/db/migrate/
20130911082405_create_admin_module.rb:7:in 'block in change'
c:/Sites/site/db/migrate/20130911082405_create_admin_module.rb:3:in 'change'
C:in 'migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm confused to as why I'm receiving this error. I'm pretty sure decimal is a valid datatype? I am using decimal as I'm dealing with currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spelling mistake in line :

```
t.deciaml :option_3_multiplier
```

Change it to :

```
t.decimal :option_3_multiplier
```